# How to align the memory using Hexagon intrinsics?

Tags: hexagon-dsp

In an array of short type, i want to access the 1st element using intrinsics of hexagon but when I use that am getting the value of a 4th element . What is the problem? Is there any intrinsic to do that?

Comment: Can you share the code you're using where you're getting the wrong result?